# NameError("name 'filename' is not defined",)

Tags: python

I have this error when I'm trying to run this code, maybe anyone can help me and give me directions.

After that problem will be solved, I need to create a loop that searching in all the xml files and finding a string, if that sting is in the file than it will move the file to the directory, anyone have an idea how can I do it?

```
import os
import glob
import shutil

def remove_ext(list_of_pathnames):
    """
    removes the extension from each filename
    """
    return [os.path.splitext(filename)[0] for filename in list_of_pathnames]

path = os.getcwd()
os.chdir("D:\\TomProject\\Images\\")   
os.mkdir("Done\\")     # create a new folder
newpath = os.path.join("D:\\TomProject\\","image_with_xml") # made it os independent... 

list_of_jpgs = glob.glob(path+"*.jpg")
list_of_xmls = glob.glob(path+"*.xml")
list_of_txts = glob.glob(path+"*.txt")

print(list_of_jpgs, "\n\n", list_of_xmls, "\n\n", list_of_txts) #remove

jpgs_without_extension = remove_ext(list_of_jpgs)
xmls_without_extension = remove_ext(list_of_xmls)
txts_without_extension = remove_ext(list_of_txts)

for filename in jpgs_without_extension:
 if filename in xmls_without_extension:
  if filename in txts_without_extension:
   print("moving", filename) #remove
shutil.move(filename + '*.jpg', newpath) # move image to new path.
shutil.move(filename + '*.xml', newpath)
shutil.move(filename + '*.txt', newpath)
```

Comment: should the last 3 lines be inside the for loop? because otherwise that `filename` variable is not available to use

Answer (score 0):

1. make sure all jpg, xml, txt are in the current working directory. you may add one line to check current directory with

```py
print(path)
```

2. please change the lines

```py
list_of_jpgs = glob.glob(path+"*.jpg")
list_of_xmls = glob.glob(path+"*.xml")
list_of_txts = glob.glob(path+"*.txt")
```

to

```py
list_of_jpgs = glob.glob(os.path.join(path,"*.jpg"))
list_of_xmls = glob.glob(os.path.join(path,"*.xml"))
list_of_txts = glob.glob(os.path.join(path,"*.txt"))
```

3. last three lines should be indented. and * should be removed.

```py
for filename in jpgs_without_extension:
 if filename in xmls_without_extension:
  if filename in txts_without_extension:
   print("moving", filename) #remove
   shutil.move(filename + '.jpg', newpath) # move image to new path.
   shutil.move(filename + '.xml', newpath)
   shutil.move(filename + '.txt', newpath)
```

Comment: it work fine now, thank you! now it creates a folder but somehow it does not moving the files to the folder

Comment: does it have another error? have you checked "D:\TomProject\image_with_xml" folder?

Comment: no error, it created the folder but the folder is empty

Comment: please delete \* in the '\*.jpg', '\*.xml', '\*.txt'

Comment: i deleted it and still it does not move the files, when i run the code it prints empty [] maybe that would help

Comment: I meant `shutil.move(filename + '.jpg', newpath)`. not the glob function

Comment: yes that is what i did, still not working.

Comment: please check all files are in the current directory. i've edited my answer. please follow that.

Comment: i have followed your answer but still it does not work, when i run the code it print me the following:                     C:\Users\User\source\repos\PythonApplication2\PythonApplication2
[]

 []

 []
Press any key to continue . . .

Comment: please change the order of two lines
path = os.getcwd() and 
os.chdir("D:\\TomProject\\Images\\")